# A painter example with tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is some code from http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_canvas.php :

```
canvas_height = 150

def paint( event ):
   python_green = "#476042"
   x1, y1 = ( event.x - 1 ), ( event.y - 1 )
   x2, y2 = ( event.x + 1 ), ( event.y + 1 )
   w.create_oval( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = python_green )

master = Tk()
master.title( "Painting using Ovals" )
w = Canvas(master, 
           width=canvas_width, 
           height=canvas_height)
w.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
w.bind( "", paint )

message = Label( master, text = "Press and Drag the mouse to draw" )
message.pack( side = BOTTOM )

mainloop()
```

It's supposed to create a painting app, but I got an error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: no events specified in binding
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify an event name as the first argument to `bind`. If you want a circle to be drawn everywhere the user drags the cursor, try B1-Motion.

```
w.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)
```

I don't know why the tutorial left that argument blank. The empty string is not a valid event name. I'm guessing they intended to fill it in later, but forgot about it.

Comment: Most likely the event is in the code for the page, but because they didn't escape the less-than sign, the browser treats it as an invalid HTML tag and ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event. You can check these pages for Tkinter
[Events and](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_events_binds.php) [Binds](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) options